# Vim Latex-Suite: macro expands but doesn't disappear

Tags: vim

I'm learning to use the Vim Latex-Suite for the first time (although I'm experienced with both Latex and Vim separately) and the macro expansion doesn't seem to be working as it should. For example, when I press `EFI` in insert mode, I get the figure environment, but it appends to the "EFI" instead of replacing it, like so:

```
EFI\begin{figure}[<+htpb+>]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{<+file+>}
        \caption{<+caption text+>}
        \label{fig:dfkkj}
\end{figure}<++>
```

This is also the case with other macros. How can I solve this? I'm using gVim on a Windows 7 machine.